# Problem in Hythothesis of a given problem

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

> Let $f$ be a meromorphic function in a neighborhood of the closed unit disk $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$. Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ and 
>   $$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n $$
>   for $z \in \mathbb{D}$. Prove that if $f$ has a pole on the unit circle $\mathbb{T}$ then the above power series diverges at any $z \in \mathbb{T}$.

This question has been posted before and has a solution.
My question is what if I don't assume that

> $f$ be a meromorphic function in a neighborhood of the closed unit disk $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$.

The solution posted also does not use this hypothesis.

Can I assume that the statement is redundant? How does it affect the problem?